# Reverse for 'display_data' not found. 'display_data' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am getting the below error when I am trying to load the home page:

```
Reverse for 'display_data' not found. 'display_data' is not a valid view function or pattern name
```

My views.py file is as follows:

```
def home(request):
    #query_results = QRC_DB.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'display_data.html')

def display_data(request,component):
    #query_results = QRC_DB.objects.all()
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at the component %s." % component)
```

My urls.py file under the app is as follows:

```
from django.urls import path
from fusioncharts import views

urlpatterns = [
        path('home/', views.home, name=''),
]
```

The urls.py file under the project is as follows:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('fusioncharts.urls'))
]
```

And my html file (display_data) code is as follows :

```
{% block content %}
  <h3>Display the test results</h3>
  <div id="container" style="width: 75%;">
    <canvas id="display-data"></canvas>
    <li><a href="{% url 'display_data' 'SQL' %}">SQL</a></li>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Can anyone please help me to find out the mistake ?

Thanks.

Comment: You have not added to `urls.py`  the `display_data` view. There is only a url for the home view

Comment: So in the urls.py, we need to add all the methods in the views.py file? So I have to write something like this: 
urlpatterns = [
        path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
        path('display-data/', views.display_data, name='display-data'"),
]

Please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Yess, thats correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `urls.py` file doesn't contain any url for `display_data`.

When you're trying to click the link rendered in the HTML tag, namely, 
`<li><a href="{% url 'display_data' 'SQL' %}">SQL</a></li>`

it tries to resolve the URL `display_data`.

First, it checks the root `urls.py` file. Among the following:

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('fusioncharts.urls'))
```

it matches the second one. Then it loads the `fusioncharts.urls` but the `fusioncharts.urls` doesn't contain any URL for `display_data`. That's why you are getting the error.

The `urls.py` file should be like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from fusioncharts import views

urlpatterns = [
        path('home/', views.home, name=''),
        path('display_data/<str:arg>', views.display_data, name='display_data'),

]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But now I am getting the next error as follows: 
Reverse for 'display_data' with arguments '('SQL',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['display_data\\/$']

So can you please what's going wrong now?

Comment: You're providing an argument with your url but in your URL definition, you didn't define it. 
You should edit your question or post a new one!

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check

Answer (score 1):

```
# There is a change in urls.py and in your template 'display_data.html'

urls.py

urlpatterns = [
        path('home/', views.home, name=''), 
        path('display_data/<str:component>', views.display_data, name='display_data'),
]


display_data.html 

{% block content %}
  <h3>Display the test results</h3>
  <div id="container" style="width: 75%;">
    <canvas id="display-data"></canvas>
    <li><a href="{% url 'display_data' component='SQL' %}">SQL</a></li>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```